# Running into segmentation fault when creating a PyQt5 application with PyInstaller under MacOs

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I tried building an application with `PyQt5` using `PyInstaller` on macOS 12.0.1. When running the application I get

```
zsh: segmentation fault
```

I recreated the fault with this short code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QHBoxLayout, QLabel

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.label = QLabel("test", self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    demo = MainWindow()
    demo.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I create the application using:

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --log-level=ERROR \
--clean \
--onefile \
--windowed \
--name Blabla \
--debug all \
--hidden-import PyQt5 \
--hidden-import PyQt5.sip \
--hidden-import PyQt5.QtWidgets \
--hidden-import PyQt5.QtGui \
--hidden-import PyQt5.QtCore \
test.py
```

The full error log is:

```
[19651] PyInstaller Bootloader 3.x
[19651] LOADER: executable is /Users/mazze/PycharmProjects/test/dist/est
[19651] LOADER: homepath is /Users/mazze/PycharmProjects/test/dist
[19651] LOADER: _MEIPASS2 is NULL
[19651] LOADER: archivename is /Users/mazze/PycharmProjects/test/dist/test
[19651] LOADER: Cookie found at offset 0x1B11266
[19651] LOADER: Extracting binaries
[19651] LOADER: Executing self as child
[19651] LOADER: set _MEIPASS2 to /var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E
[19651] LOADER [AppleEvent]: Processing...
[19651] LOADER [AppleEvent]: Installed handlers.
[19651] LOADER [AppleEvent]: Calling ReceiveNextEvent
[19651] LOADER [AppleEvent]: ReceiveNextEvent got an EVENT
[19651] LOADER [AppleEvent]: Dispatching event...
[19651] LOADER [AppleEvent]: App event handler proc called.
[19651] LOADER [AppleEvent]: what=23 message=61657674 ('aevt') modifiers=0
[19651] LOADER [AppleEvent]: Ignored event.
[19651] LOADER [AppleEvent]: Calling ReceiveNextEvent
[19651] LOADER [AppleEvent]: ReceiveNextEvent timed out
[19651] LOADER [AppleEvent]: Out of the event loop.
[19651] LOADER: Registering signal handlers
[19651] LOADER [AppleEvent]: Processing...
[19651] LOADER [AppleEvent]: Calling ReceiveNextEvent
[19653] PyInstaller Bootloader 3.x
[19653] LOADER: executable is /Users/mazze/PycharmProjects/test/dist/test
[19653] LOADER: homepath is /Users/mazze/PycharmProjects/test/dist
[19653] LOADER: _MEIPASS2 is /var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E
[19653] LOADER: archivename is /Users/mazze/PycharmProjects/test/dist/test
[19653] LOADER: Cookie found at offset 0x1B11266
[19653] LOADER: Already in the child - running user's code.
[19653] LOADER: Python library: /var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/Python3
[19653] LOADER: Loaded functions from Python library.
[19653] LOADER: Manipulating environment (sys.path, sys.prefix)
[19653] LOADER: sys.prefix is /var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E
[19653] LOADER: Pre-init sys.path is /var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/base_library.zip:/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/lib-dynload:/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E
[19653] LOADER: Setting runtime options
[19653] LOADER: Runtime option: v
[19653] LOADER: Initializing python
import _frozen_importlib # frozen
import _imp # builtin
import '_thread' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import '_warnings' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import '_weakref' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import '_frozen_importlib_external' # <class '_frozen_importlib.FrozenImporter'>
import '_io' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'marshal' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'posix' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import _thread # previously loaded ('_thread')
import '_thread' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import _weakref # previously loaded ('_weakref')
import '_weakref' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# installing zipimport hook
import 'time' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'zipimport' # <class '_frozen_importlib.FrozenImporter'>
# installed zipimport hook
# zipimport: found 148 names in '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/base_library.zip'
import '_codecs' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import codecs # loaded from Zip /var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/base_library.zip/codecs.pyc
import encodings.aliases # loaded from Zip /var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/base_library.zip/encodings/aliases.pyc
import encodings.cp437 # loaded from Zip /var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/base_library.zip/encodings/cp437.pyc
import encodings # loaded from Zip /var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/base_library.zip/encodings/__init__.pyc
import encodings.utf_8 # loaded from Zip /var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/base_library.zip/encodings/utf_8.pyc
import '_signal' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import encodings.latin_1 # loaded from Zip /var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/base_library.zip/encodings/latin_1.pyc
import '_abc' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import abc # loaded from Zip /var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/base_library.zip/abc.pyc
import io # loaded from Zip /var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/base_library.zip/io.pyc
[19653] LOADER: Overriding Python's sys.path
[19653] LOADER: Post-init sys.path is /var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/base_library.zip:/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/lib-dynload:/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E
[19653] LOADER: Setting sys.argv
[19653] LOADER: setting sys._MEIPASS
[19653] LOADER: importing modules from CArchive
[19653] LOADER: extracted struct
[19653] LOADER: callfunction returned...
# extension module '_struct' loaded from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/lib-dynload/_struct.cpython-38-darwin.so'
# extension module '_struct' executed from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/lib-dynload/_struct.cpython-38-darwin.so'
import '_struct' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x10c450970>
[19653] LOADER: extracted pyimod01_os_path
[19653] LOADER: callfunction returned...
[19653] LOADER: extracted pyimod02_archive
[19653] LOADER: callfunction returned...
# extension module 'zlib' loaded from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/lib-dynload/zlib.cpython-38-darwin.so'
# extension module 'zlib' executed from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/lib-dynload/zlib.cpython-38-darwin.so'
import 'zlib' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x10c4653d0>
[19653] LOADER: extracted pyimod03_importers
[19653] LOADER: callfunction returned...
[19653] LOADER: Installing PYZ archive with Python modules.
[19653] LOADER: PYZ archive: PYZ-00.pyz
[19653] LOADER: Running pyiboot01_bootstrap.py
# PyInstaller: FrozenImporter(/Users/mazze/PycharmProjects/test/dist/test?28365440)
# os not found in PYZ
# code object from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/os.pyc'
# stat not found in PYZ
# code object from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/stat.pyc'
import '_stat' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'stat' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourcelessFileLoader object at 0x10c486a30>
# _collections_abc not found in PYZ
import _collections_abc # loaded from Zip /var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/base_library.zip/_collections_abc.pyc
# posixpath not found in PYZ
# code object from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/posixpath.pyc'
# genericpath not found in PYZ
# code object from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/genericpath.pyc'
import 'genericpath' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourcelessFileLoader object at 0x10c50f9d0>
import 'posixpath' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourcelessFileLoader object at 0x10c48ea90>
import 'os' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourcelessFileLoader object at 0x10c476220>
# ctypes not found in PYZ
# code object from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/ctypes/__init__.pyc'
# _ctypes not found in PYZ
# extension module '_ctypes' loaded from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-38-darwin.so'
# extension module '_ctypes' executed from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-38-darwin.so'
import '_ctypes' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x10c522d60>
# ctypes._endian not found in PYZ
# code object from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/ctypes/_endian.pyc'
import 'ctypes._endian' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourcelessFileLoader object at 0x10c52dbb0>
import 'ctypes' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourcelessFileLoader object at 0x10c476a90>
# ctypes.macholib not found in PYZ
[19653] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_pyqt5.py
[19653] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py
# re not found in PYZ
# enum not found in PYZ
# types not found in PYZ
import types # loaded from Zip /var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/base_library.zip/types.pyc
import enum # loaded from Zip /var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/base_library.zip/enum.pyc
# sre_compile not found in PYZ
import '_sre' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# sre_parse not found in PYZ
# sre_constants not found in PYZ
import sre_constants # loaded from Zip /var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/base_library.zip/sre_constants.pyc
import sre_parse # loaded from Zip /var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/base_library.zip/sre_parse.pyc
import sre_compile # loaded from Zip /var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/base_library.zip/sre_compile.pyc
# functools not found in PYZ
# collections not found in PYZ
# operator not found in PYZ
import '_operator' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import operator # loaded from Zip /var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/base_library.zip/operator.pyc
# keyword not found in PYZ
import keyword # loaded from Zip /var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/base_library.zip/keyword.pyc
# heapq not found in PYZ
# _heapq not found in PYZ
# extension module '_heapq' loaded from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/lib-dynload/_heapq.cpython-38-darwin.so'
# extension module '_heapq' executed from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/lib-dynload/_heapq.cpython-38-darwin.so'
import '_heapq' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x10c5b3af0>
import heapq # loaded from Zip /var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/base_library.zip/heapq.pyc
import 'itertools' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# reprlib not found in PYZ
import reprlib # loaded from Zip /var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/base_library.zip/reprlib.pyc
import '_collections' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import collections # loaded from Zip /var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/base_library.zip/collections/__init__.pyc
import '_functools' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import functools # loaded from Zip /var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/base_library.zip/functools.pyc
import '_locale' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# copyreg not found in PYZ
import copyreg # loaded from Zip /var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/base_library.zip/copyreg.pyc
import re # loaded from Zip /var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/base_library.zip/re.pyc
# multiprocessing not found in PYZ
# code object from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/multiprocessing/__init__.pyc'
# multiprocessing.context not found in PYZ
# code object from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/multiprocessing/context.pyc'
# threading not found in PYZ
# code object from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/threading.pyc'
# _weakrefset not found in PYZ
import _weakrefset # loaded from Zip /var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/base_library.zip/_weakrefset.pyc
import 'threading' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourcelessFileLoader object at 0x10c5e90a0>
# multiprocessing.process not found in PYZ
# code object from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/multiprocessing/process.pyc'
# signal not found in PYZ
# code object from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/signal.pyc'
import 'signal' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourcelessFileLoader object at 0x10c6418e0>
import 'multiprocessing.process' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourcelessFileLoader object at 0x10c5f3670>
# multiprocessing.reduction not found in PYZ
# code object from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/multiprocessing/reduction.pyc'
# pickle not found in PYZ
# code object from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/pickle.pyc'
# _compat_pickle not found in PYZ
# code object from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/_compat_pickle.pyc'
import '_compat_pickle' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourcelessFileLoader object at 0x10c66b8b0>
# _pickle not found in PYZ
# extension module '_pickle' loaded from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/lib-dynload/_pickle.cpython-38-darwin.so'
# extension module '_pickle' executed from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/lib-dynload/_pickle.cpython-38-darwin.so'
import '_pickle' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x10c66bac0>
# org not found in PYZ
import 'pickle' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourcelessFileLoader object at 0x10c64fd90>
# socket not found in PYZ
# code object from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/socket.pyc'
# _socket not found in PYZ
# extension module '_socket' loaded from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/lib-dynload/_socket.cpython-38-darwin.so'
# extension module '_socket' executed from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/lib-dynload/_socket.cpython-38-darwin.so'
import '_socket' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x10c68d6a0>
# selectors not found in PYZ
# code object from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/selectors.pyc'
# collections.abc not found in PYZ
import collections.abc # loaded from Zip /var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/base_library.zip/collections/abc.pyc
# math not found in PYZ
# extension module 'math' loaded from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/lib-dynload/math.cpython-38-darwin.so'
# extension module 'math' executed from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/lib-dynload/math.cpython-38-darwin.so'
import 'math' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x10c69e9a0>
# select not found in PYZ
# extension module 'select' loaded from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/lib-dynload/select.cpython-38-darwin.so'
# extension module 'select' executed from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/lib-dynload/select.cpython-38-darwin.so'
import 'select' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x10c69ea30>
import 'selectors' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourcelessFileLoader object at 0x10c68d760>
import 'errno' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'socket' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourcelessFileLoader object at 0x10c64ffa0>
# array not found in PYZ
[19651] LOADER [AppleEvent]: ReceiveNextEvent timed out
[19651] LOADER [AppleEvent]: Out of the event loop.
[19651] LOADER [AppleEvent]: Processing...
[19651] LOADER [AppleEvent]: Calling ReceiveNextEvent
# extension module 'array' loaded from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/lib-dynload/array.cpython-38-darwin.so'
# extension module 'array' executed from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/lib-dynload/array.cpython-38-darwin.so'
import 'array' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x10c6ab700>
import 'multiprocessing.reduction' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourcelessFileLoader object at 0x10c6419a0>
import 'multiprocessing.context' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourcelessFileLoader object at 0x10c5af940>
import 'multiprocessing' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourcelessFileLoader object at 0x10c588580>
# multiprocessing.spawn not found in PYZ
# code object from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/multiprocessing/spawn.pyc'
# runpy not found in PYZ
# code object from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/runpy.pyc'
# importlib not found in PYZ
# code object from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/importlib/__init__.pyc'
# warnings not found in PYZ
import warnings # loaded from Zip /var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/base_library.zip/warnings.pyc
import 'importlib' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourcelessFileLoader object at 0x10c6abbe0>
# importlib.machinery not found in PYZ
# code object from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/importlib/machinery.pyc'
import 'importlib.machinery' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourcelessFileLoader object at 0x10c6abe20>
# importlib.util not found in PYZ
# code object from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/importlib/util.pyc'
# importlib.abc not found in PYZ
# code object from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/importlib/abc.pyc'
import 'importlib.abc' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourcelessFileLoader object at 0x10c757cd0>
# contextlib not found in PYZ
# code object from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/contextlib.pyc'
import 'contextlib' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourcelessFileLoader object at 0x10c763070>
import 'importlib.util' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourcelessFileLoader object at 0x10c7575b0>
# pkgutil not found in PYZ
# code object from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/pkgutil.pyc'
# weakref not found in PYZ
import weakref # loaded from Zip /var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/base_library.zip/weakref.pyc
import 'pkgutil' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourcelessFileLoader object at 0x10c763d60>
import 'runpy' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourcelessFileLoader object at 0x10c66b790>
# multiprocessing.util not found in PYZ
# code object from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/multiprocessing/util.pyc'
import 'atexit' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# subprocess not found in PYZ
# code object from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/subprocess.pyc'
# msvcrt not found in PYZ
# _posixsubprocess not found in PYZ
# extension module '_posixsubprocess' loaded from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/lib-dynload/_posixsubprocess.cpython-38-darwin.so'
# extension module '_posixsubprocess' executed from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/lib-dynload/_posixsubprocess.cpython-38-darwin.so'
import '_posixsubprocess' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x10c7a3f70>
import 'subprocess' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourcelessFileLoader object at 0x10c795dc0>
import 'multiprocessing.util' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourcelessFileLoader object at 0x10c7712e0>
import 'multiprocessing.spawn' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourcelessFileLoader object at 0x10c52dfd0>
# multiprocessing.popen_fork not found in PYZ
# code object from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/multiprocessing/popen_fork.pyc'
import 'multiprocessing.popen_fork' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourcelessFileLoader object at 0x10c5b8b50>
# multiprocessing.popen_spawn_posix not found in PYZ
# code object from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_posix.pyc'
import 'multiprocessing.popen_spawn_posix' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourcelessFileLoader object at 0x10c7a3280>
[19653] LOADER: Running test.py
# PyQt5 not found in PYZ
# code object from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/PyQt5/__init__.pyc'
import 'PyQt5' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourcelessFileLoader object at 0x10c7b9220>
# PyQt5.QtWidgets not found in PYZ
# PyQt5.sip not found in PYZ
# extension module 'PyQt5.sip' loaded from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/PyQt5/sip.cpython-38-darwin.so'
# extension module 'PyQt5.sip' executed from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/PyQt5/sip.cpython-38-darwin.so'
import 'PyQt5.sip' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x10c7b94c0>
# PyQt5.QtCore not found in PYZ
[19651] LOADER [AppleEvent]: ReceiveNextEvent timed out
[19651] LOADER [AppleEvent]: Out of the event loop.
[19651] LOADER [AppleEvent]: Processing...
[19651] LOADER [AppleEvent]: Calling ReceiveNextEvent
# extension module 'PyQt5.QtCore' loaded from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/PyQt5/QtCore.abi3.so'
# extension module 'PyQt5.QtCore' executed from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/PyQt5/QtCore.abi3.so'
import 'PyQt5.QtCore' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x10c7b96d0>
# PyQt5.QtGui not found in PYZ
# extension module 'PyQt5.QtGui' loaded from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/PyQt5/QtGui.abi3.so'
# extension module 'PyQt5.QtGui' executed from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/PyQt5/QtGui.abi3.so'
import 'PyQt5.QtGui' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x10c869c70>
# extension module 'PyQt5.QtWidgets' loaded from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/PyQt5/QtWidgets.abi3.so'
# extension module 'PyQt5.QtWidgets' executed from '/var/folders/cz/2jgcg2gj48xby69d5xhc6vt00000gn/T/_MEI8cjd8E/PyQt5/QtWidgets.abi3.so'
import 'PyQt5.QtWidgets' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x10c7b91c0>
[19651] LOADER [AppleEvent]: ReceiveNextEvent timed out
[19651] LOADER [AppleEvent]: Out of the event loop.
[19651] LOADER: Restoring signal handlers
[19651] LOADER: freeing args
[19651] LOADER: re-raising child signal 11
zsh: segmentation fault  /Users/mazze/PycharmProjects/test/dist/test
```

The following versions are used:

- PyInstaller: 4.3
- Python: 3.8.9
- PyQt5: 5.13.0

Creating the app under Windows works fine. The problem only occurs under Mac. I know there are some questions about this, but I couldn't find an answer hat worked for me. The suggestions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67057304/pyinstaller-on-macos-bigsur-cannot-build-basic-pyqt5-app) did not work

Creating the app with `py2app` works fine. The file just gets really big.

Comment: See if any of the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67057304/pyinstaller-on-macos-bigsur-cannot-build-basic-pyqt5-app) might help. You're just creating a layout, not setting it, which btw shouldn't be done, since QMainWindow already has its own private layout.

Comment: I already tried those suggestions. It didn't work.

Comment: Then please [edit] your post and provide the full error log.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66848968/segmentation-fault-11-while-creating-executable-with-pyinstaller) and installing pyinstaller with

```
pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/tarball/develop
```